# app crashes with special characters binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, character-encoding

I have an app, where I load data from a server, and display it to the user. The problem is, that the server returns some special characters like ܘ (code 1816 in UTF-8), which seems to be some arabic letters that are right to left.

When I try to bind them to my views like this

```
<pre ng-bind="json"></pre>
```

my Chrome crashes. I've created a Plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/CvbU7VTEl3dmj1JElIz5?p=preview

It works fine in Firefox 33 and Safar 7.1 on my Mac. However, Chrome 40 on my Mac crashes most of the time (try to reload it a few times).

If it is a browser issue, is there a workaround, to replace this characters when they are returned by the server?

And if it is an angular problem, how could I debug this behaviour when the whole tab crashes?

Comment: The character “ܘ” is U+0718 SYRIAC LETTER WAW (which is a right-to-left character).

Comment: THis is a browser issue, probably  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=433468

Comment: Ok, any idea how to work around this issue? Like replacing these characters with a questionmark, before it is injected into HTML?